# Group tableview header show on admob banner

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, admob

when I scroll tableview then my tableview is going back to admob but group header show on ad so, how can I solve this issue.

[image]

I want this type of output when scroll tableview

[image]

Comment: Set prpoer Frames of your UITableView.

Comment: its UITableview controller and set banner view in bottom of tableview controller

Answer (score 0):

instand of

```
  [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
```

use this method

– insertSubview:aboveSubview:

addsubview will add view in same layer. this will add your view on above table.